# caddy - setting https to localhost on mac

Tags: https, httpserver, caddy, localserver, caddyfile

I am using caddy `v2.3.0` on mac

If run `caddy run` i am getting following
[image]

My `Caddyfile`

```
{
    local_certs
}

demoCart.dev:443 {
    reverse_proxy http://localhost:3000
}
```

If I run `caddy validate` it says `Valid configuration`

When I am trying to access it on the browser with `https://democart.dev`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but this looks like a DNS issue rather than a caddy issue.

Have you set up your DNS to point democart.dev to your machine?  Caddy will only be able to serve it if it points to your machines IP address in the first place.

Try

```
localhost:443 {
    reverse_proxy http://localhost:3000
}
```

and see if that works.